# Missing return statement error even with return statement at the end of method

Tags: java

I have this method to search for files and store them into a list and return it. The problem is that I get an "This method must return a result of type List" even I have a return statement of type List at the end of it.

```
public List<String> cautaFisiere(String root) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    File[] file = new File(root).listFiles();
    if (file == null) {
        return ;
    }
    for (File x : file) {
        if (x.getName().toLowerCase().contains(fileName.toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println(x.getName() + " " + x.getPath());
        }
        String path = x.getPath();
        if (x.isDirectory()) {
            cautaFisiere(path);

        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

the error is on the 5th line in my code

Comment: If `file == null`, what do you return then?

Comment: Have a look at `return ;` - you're probably told that this is the line the error is related to by your IDE or the compiler.

Comment: You have to return some value, you probably want either `return null;` or `return Collections.emptyList();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<String> cautaFisiere(String root) {
  ...
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  ...

    if (file == null) {
        return ;
    }
  ...
}
```

is not legal as the method should return a List of String.

So you could write :

```
if (file == null) {
    return null ;
}
```

or

```
if (file == null) {
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fix that by returning null.

```
 if (file == null) {
    return null;
 }
```

Edit: I suppose you're right.

```
if (file == null) {
   return list;
}
```

Comment: Bad idea.  He should return the (empty) list

Comment: @StephenC - Or perhaps throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement currently does not return anything. Make it return an empty list

Answer (score 0):

This is a better solution:

```
if (file == null) {
    return list;
}
```

If you return `null` then the caller has to deal with the `null` as a special case.  An empty list (which is what `list` is at that point) can be treated (pretty much) the same way as a non-empty list.

As @Ted Hopp suggests, throwing an exception would be another way to deal with this.  It depends on whether you want / need to treat the case where the `root` directory is empty as exceptional / erroneous ... or as something that doesn't matter.

- If you do want this to be "exceptional", it is a good idea.
- If not, throwing an exception would be making unnecessary work for code further up the call stack.